# Transparent Darkroom paper

Tags: darkroom, paper

I am looking for a product that I used in college to produce B&W transparent prints in a darkroom. It used the traditional dev, stop, fix process and the final image could be backlit. I have done the webresearch but with the billions of ink jet and digital options I’m guessing it’s a needle in a haystack situation.  Any help?

Comment: I didn't find a black and white version, but could it have been something like [Fujitrans Crystal Archive](https://www.fujifilmusa.com/products/photofinishing/paper_lab_products/color_papers_printing_materials/fujitrans_display_material/index.html) or [Kodak Endura Clear](https://imaging.kodakalaris.com/product/kodak-professional-endura-transparency-and-clear-display-materials)?

Comment: I just received my newsletter from *Freestyle photo and imaging supplies* today and it say that ILFORD  is once again offering their ULF  program.   *"Their ULF program allows Ultra Large Format photographers the opportunity to order large or special sizes of ILFORD sheet and roll films, without (most of) the constraints of the usual minimum order quantity"*.  HP5, FP4 and 100 Delta.
   https://www.freestylephoto.biz/category/2-film/black-and-white-film?attr%5B%5D=1-254&attr%5B%5D=2-6&mfg%5B%5D=54

Comment: I don't know the product you mention but you could try to emulate it with something like that with liquid light on mylar sheets. Another route would be reversal processing B+W film yourself or sending it off to dr5.com The second approach becomes much more difficult if you want to use an enlarger to form the image on the film. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Chances are the material you used is no longer made.  However you could just use film, assuming you are working from negs with an enlarger in the normal way.  In particular if you can find an orthochromatic sheet film this would be suitable.  [Ilford make one](https://www.ilfordphoto.com/ortho-sheetfilm) which is available in sheets up to 8x10 generally and 10x12 by special order.  Because it's orthochromatic it can be handled under (dim) red safelighting so it's not a complete pain to use.  It will probably be very fast compared to paper, but it is designed for copying, so it's reasonably slow (they quote ISO 80: I'm not sure what paper speeds are, but I suspect significantly lower than that).

It's going to be an expensive experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Kodak's Fine Grain Positive Film 7302 (8x10) is the only example of B&W transparency film that I'm aware of. This material can sometimes be found on eBay but it will be expired.